# Image Gallery -- select image which displays first

Tags: php, jquery, dynamic, gallery

I have photo gallery based on jQuery scrip[t from: http://coffeescripter.com/code/ad-gallery/.

Images are stored in mySQL database. I have a page with list of galleries, which displays first five images from each gallery. Clicking at any of image moves to gallery and starts displaying from first image.

I would like to do that in a such way: if user clicks on second image, displaying should start from second image, if user clicks on third image, displaying should start from third image etc.

Here is some code, which I have so far:

```
/* galleries.php */
    <?php
        $idg = $_GET["idg"];
        if (file_exists(GALLERY.'galleries.php') && $idg == '') 
        {
            require_once(GALLERY.'list_galleries.php');
        }
        else if (file_exists(GALLERY.'galleries.php') && $idg != '' )
        {
            require_once(GALLERY.'view_gallery.php');
        }
    ?>
```

/* list_galleries.php */

```
<?php

    $sql_gal = "SELECT id_g, nazwa FROM page_gallery WHERE widok=1";
    $res_gal = @mysql_query($sql_gal);
    $n = mysql_num_rows($res_gal);

    while ($row_gal = @mysql_fetch_array($res_gal)){

        $galName = $row_gal["nazwa"];

        $idg = $row_gal["id_g"];

        $sql_gal_con = "SELECT desc, img FROM page_gallery_con
            WHERE id_g='$idg' ORDER BY order ASC LIMIT 5";
        $res_gal_con = @mysql_query($sql_gal_con);


        echo '<table class="galleryTable">';
        echo '<tr >';
        echo '<td colspan="4">';
        echo '<a href="?p=13&idg='.$idg.'" class="galleryName" >'.$galName.'</a>';
        echo '</td>';
        echo '<td class="galleryCount">';
        echo '</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
        echo '<tr class="galleryRow">';

        while ($row_gal_con = @mysql_fetch_array($res_gal_con)){

            $desc = $row_gal_con["desc"];
            $img = $row_gal_con["img"];

            echo '<td class="galleryCell">';
                            echo '<a href="?p=13&idg='.$idg.'"><img src="'.GALLERY_DIR.'min/'.$img.'" alt="'.$desc.'" /></a>';
            echo '</td>';

        }
        echo '</tr>';
        echo '</table>';
    }

?>
```

---

I have found proper solution based on tips from http://webdev.plentyinfo.com/tag/ad-gallery/

Comment: And? What is your question? BTW - you need descriptive title. And without tags in it...

Comment: @NilColor, thanks for your comments, I have corrected my question. Sorry for my English.

Comment: @mkas what is widok=1 in your first query? explain the column

Comment: @AwaisQarni, it isn't very significant, I think. In CMS I can show or hide galleries. If gallery is avaiable variable `widok` equals 1, otherwise 0.

Answer (score 1):

just add a if condition to check if your `$_GET` variable is set or not. For example before your second query change your code like this

```
 if(isset($_GET['idg']))
 $idg=$_GET['idg'];
 else
 $idg = $row_gal["id_g"];
```

Comment: I'm not sure if you understand my problem correctly. I would like to get direct link to the specific image in a gallery:`?p=13&idg=4#image-id`, where p=13 - page with galleries, idg - id of gallery, #image-id - anchor to particular image in gallery.